# Python code to cause a backspace keystroke?

Tags: python, keystroke, backspace

I keep finding ways to map the backspace key differently, but that's not what I'm after.

I'm in a program writing a python code, and basically I want to write a line of code that causes the program to think someone just hit the Backspace key in the GUI (as the backspace key deletes something)

How I would code in a backspace key stroke?

Comment: What context are the keystrokes taking place in?  A Tkinter Text widget?  Some other GUI framework?

Comment: maybe i should specify a bi more. Im not actually deleting a character here using \b. Basically in this program think of it as image tracking, and it places a mark on high contrast points of an image. When you adjust the error threshold it hilights points with a high error. Pressing backspace on the GUI viewer deletes the selected points. Thats what i want.

Comment: Ok, then you need an event listener.  For example, in Tkinter, you would bind a function to [the `<BackSpace>` event](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm).  It's hard to help you any more unless you tell us what framework you've written your GUI in.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The character for backspace is `'\b'` but it sounds like you want to affect the GUI.

if your program changes the GUI, then simply delete the last character from the active input field.

Comment: maybe i should specify a bi more. Im not actually deleting a character here using \b. Basically in this program think of it as image tracking, and it places a mark on high contrast points of an image. When you adjust the error threshold it hilights points with a high error. Pressing backspace on the GUI viewer deletes the selected points. Thats what i want.

Comment: delete_points() is what? Theres no actual script command for deleting the points that i can call out. I need the keystroke automated. I dont mean i want to cause backspace to have an action. I want to make it so as my script cycles through it will analyze, then delete points, move to next frame, analyze, delete etc - But again - theres no script that it gives me access to to cause the delete_points() action. what i want would be something like:
blahblah['addAnalysysKey'].execute()
pythonCommandToCauseKeysroke['\b'].stroke()

etccc

Comment: So you're trying to inject a backspace into the program's keystrokes?  That depends on your program and environment.  If you're talking about a Windows app, you need to ask Windows GUI people.

Answer (score 9):

and i got it !

```
import sys

print('\b ', end="", flush=True) 
sys.stdout.write('\010')
```

it backspace !

Comment: This worked for me!!
Example: trying to erase the final comma and place a period.

=======
def fibonacci(f):
    x = z = 0
    y = 1

    while z <= f:
        if z == 0:
            z = z+x
        else:
            z = x+y

        if z <= f:
            print("{}, ".format(z), end="")

        x = y
        y = z
    else:
        print('\010\010.') 


print("fibonacci")
fibonacci(30)

Answer (score 5):

```
foo = "abc"
foo = foo + "\b" + "xyz"
print foo
>> abxyz
print len(foo)
>> 7

if key == '\b': delete_selected_points()
```

Comment: maybe i should specify a bi more. Im not actually deleting a character here using \b. Basically in this program think of it as image tracking, and it places a mark on high contrast points of an image. When you adjust the error threshold it hilights points with a high error. Pressing backspace on the GUI viewer deletes the selected points. Thats what i want.

Comment: What Brent said, unless I'm missing something.

Answer (score 4):

As other answers have said, use '\b' to backspace. The trick in your case is to use sys.stdout.write instead of print to not get a newline appended. Then wait and print the appropriate number of backspace characters.

```
import time
import sys

print("Good morning!")
while True:
    time_fmt = "It's %I:%M:%S %p on %A, %b %d, %Y"
    time_str = time.strftime(time_fmt)
    sys.stdout.write(time_str)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(1)
    sys.stdout.write("\b"*len(time_str))
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating since this still pops up in search.
In Python3 `print()` can and does work if you use the `\<end\>` parameter.  Meaning `sys.stdout.write()` and `.flush()` aren't needed.

eg.
`print("\b"*len(time_str),end='')`