# How can i change an already printed out character into another discarding the printed text?

Tags: python

Can i change an already printed out character to another while having the previous deleted? For example how can a program show '_' for 2 seconds, (delete or change it) and show the character 's'?

Comment: i want to replace '_' with 's' (not numbers)

Comment: @Smart Then the question [Python code to cause a backspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18320431/python-code-to-cause-a-backspace-keystroke) might be a little more helpful to you. The answers are very similar to those of the duplicate, but it focuses on how to make a backspace. In particular, the newest answer shows an example of a time based erasure which is replaced by new set of characters, which you could tweak to your `"_"` to `"s"` example pretty simply.

Comment: then change the code to that which you want: `sys.stdout.write('%s\r' % '_'); sys.stdout.flush(); time.sleep(2); sys.stdout.write('%s\n' % 's')`

Answer (score 0):

The character for **backspace** is `'\b'`.

The usage for the task you're asking for would be something like this

```
import sys, time

print('I am about to show you something _\b', end='')
sys.stdout.flush() # Make sure above string gets printed in time
time.sleep(2)
print('THIS!')
```

---

In addition, the character for **carriage return** is `'\r'` and it allows you to rewrite the whole line. You could use it, for example to print a **progress bar**

```
import sys, time
for i in range(0, 50):
    print('[{}{}] {}%'.format('|' * i, '-' * (50-1-i), 2*i+2), end='\r')
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(0.01)
print('')
```

Comment: your first code line 3 (first 'print') generates a syntax error

Comment: @smart are you sure you copy/pasted it right? It runs on my computer and on online compilers too. What does the error say?

Comment: just a syntax error

Comment: @smart what python version are you using?

Comment: i am using 2.4.3

Comment: @smart so that's because `print` is still a statement, not a function. Replace it with `sys.stdout.write('I am about to show you something _\b')`

Comment: now it generates a type error: 'write() takes no keyboard arguments'

Comment: @smart what if you convert the string to bytes literal? `sys.stdout.write(b'I am about to show you something _\b')`

Comment: now it generates a syntax error

Comment: @smart I'm not sure why you have that type error on `write()`. See [here](https://tio.run/##TY0xDsIwEAT7vGIRhRMJpeAVpKCCEgklyhFb4FzkOxP59caBhm52pdldklqejzk7v3BQSJID1HmqqoKt6MhR2zU4pdp06D36oTRQhlhekThC2JNaN0@43wbT/IuPVxRbN9jj3D8JEgNtA@@CGjZjIhUsBZVGuPl3/c21uZ66y840OX8A) the code runs fine (except `\b` is not recognized)